# Is there a way to get the complete text of the row from the dataframe? I wanted to see the complete Review

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

`df.iloc[14]`

*Review       great hotel night quick business trip loved li...
Rating                                                       4
Sentiment                                                    1
Name: 14, dtype: object*

Answer (score 0):

**try:**

```
complete_review = df.iloc[14]['Review']
```

**or:**

```
row_string = df.loc[row_number].to_string(sep=' ')
print(row_string)
```